# JQuery animate enhanced through webkit, inconsistent

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

The following code controls a function for sliding various items across a bar. It is using a plugin called JQuery animate enhanced that uses CSS3 where possible on supporting browsers.

Without CSS3 the function works perfectly. However with CSS3 once all tabs have been selected the first one will no longer cooperate.

the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cqBZz/3/

the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var bounceholder = 0;
    var delayact = 0;
    $('.bouncetabs a').click(function () {
        $('.bouncetabs a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');

        if ($(this).index('.bouncetabs a') < bounceholder) {
            var backwards = 1
        } else {
            var backwards = 0
        }

        bounceholder = $(this).index('.bouncetabs a');
        var bounceoffset = 0;

        if ($('.bounceholder ul:eq(' + bounceholder + ') li').length == 6) {
            var bounceoffset = 0;
        } else if ($('.bounceholder ul:eq(' + bounceholder + ') li').length == 5) {
            var bounceoffset = 72;
        } else if ($('.bounceholder ul:eq(' + bounceholder + ') li').length == 4) {
            var bounceoffset = 144;
        } else if ($('.bounceholder ul:eq(' + bounceholder + ') li').length == 3) {
            var bounceoffset = 216;
        } else if ($('.bounceholder ul:eq(' + bounceholder + ') li').length == 2) {
            var bounceoffset = 288;
        }

        $('.bounceholder ul:eq(' + bounceholder + ')').prevAll().each(function () {
            $('li', this).each(function () {
                $(this).delay(150).animate({
                    left: -200,
                    top: 0,
                    leaveTransforms: true
                }, {
                    duration: 400,
                    queue: true
                });
            });
        });
        $('.bounceholder ul:eq(' + bounceholder + ')').nextAll().each(function () {
            $('li', this).each(function () {
                $(this).delay(150).animate({
                    left: +1000,
                    top: 0,
                    leaveTransforms: true
                }, 600);
            });
        });

        if (backwards == 1) {
            bounceoffset = 800 - bounceoffset;
            $($('.bounceholder ul:eq(' + bounceholder + ') li').get().reverse()).each(function (i) {
                delay = (i + 1) * 100;
                $(this).delay(delay).animate({
                    left: +bounceoffset,
                    top: 0,
                    opacity: 0.6,
                    leaveTransforms: true
                }, {
                    duration: 400,
                    queue: true
                });
                bounceoffset -= 160;
            });
        } else {
            $('.bounceholder ul:eq(' + bounceholder + ') li').each(function (i) {
                delay = (i + 1) * (100 * delayact);
                $(this).delay(delay).animate({
                    left: +bounceoffset,
                    top: 0,
                    opacity: 0.6,
                    leaveTransforms: true
                }, {
                    duration: 400,
                    queue: true
                });
                bounceoffset += 160;
            });
        }
        delayact = 1;

        return false
    });

});
```

Comment: Any reason to not just set the 'leaveTransforms' to false? The problem is most likely somewhere in the css3 transition Jquery.animate plugin... It would be more helpful to probably be looking at that code.

Comment: @donutdan4114 Tried altering functions but even more disturbing results acheived

Answer (score 1):

The best way to deal with hardware acceleration currently is using a combination of CSS3 transition for -moz-translate, -webkit-translate and -webkit-translate3d and jQuery animate. My personal experience with the above mentioned tool is rather bad. It caused multiple errors on my pages.

Also set translateZ(0px) for all elements you want to move as translate3d is only used for safari and chrome (enables hardware acceleration)

Here's something to get started with. You have to add checks for browsers to make it work.

```
if(browser.isFF) {
    function moveDOM(jQueryObj,x,y) { 
        jQueryObj[0].style.cssText += '-moz-transform:translate('+x+'px,'+y+'px);'; 
    } // firefox does not know translate3d
} else if(browser.isAndroid) {
    function moveDOM(jQueryObj,x,y) {
        jQueryObj[0].style.cssText += '-webkit-transform:translate('+x+'px,'+y+'px);';
    } // most Android version currently don't know translate3d (U could add checks for the Android versions though -> caniuse.com
} else if(browser.isSafari || browser.isChrome) {
    function moveDOM(jQueryObj,x,y) {
        jQueryObj[0].style.cssText += '-webkit-transform:translate3d('+x+'px,'+y+'px,0px);';
    };
} else { // ie opera, others
    function moveDOM(jQueryObj,x,y) { 
        jQueryObj.animate({'left':x,'top':y},500); 
    };
}

// example run of the function, moving the element with the id myDiv to position (50,90)
moveDOM($("#myDiv"),50,90);
```

the delay for the css translates can be set via CSS3:

```
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease; -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
```

PS: you might wonder why i used default JS instead of jQuery's .css() functoin in 3 out of 4 cases... It's simply faster. If you want to increase speed even further, replace the += with = but that overwrites any other stlyes you might have added.